# How do I round a number down and take away a number in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty terrible at JS, so I know the answer is simple but whatever I try keeps breaking my script. At the moment I have this code:

```js
    var serverRequest = "https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/statistics";
    var serverData = "";

    function numberWithCommas(x) {
      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    function success(data) {
        document.getElementById("playersTotal").innerHTML = "<span>Total Players: </span>" + numberWithCommas(data['totalplayers']);
        document.getElementById("housesTotal").innerHTML = "<span>Total Houses: </span>" + numberWithCommas(data['totalhouses']);
        document.getElementById("housesTotal").innerHTML = "<span>Total Houses: </span>" + numberWithCommas(data['totalhouses']);
        document.getElementById("moneyTotal").innerHTML = "<span>GDP: </span> £" + numberWithCommas(data.economy['totalcashonhand'] + data.economy['totalcashinbank']);
    }

    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: serverRequest,
      data: serverData,
      success: success
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Server Stats - Stats Page</title>
        <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/server.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="leaderboards">
        <div class="header">
          <a href="leaderboards.html">Leaderboards</a>
          <a href="#" class="active">Server stats</a>
          <a href="../index.html">Search</a>
        </div>
        <div class="playerdata">
            <div class="head">
                <h1><span>Server</span> Statistics</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="server">
                <div>
                    <h2 id="playersTotal">...</h2>
                    <h2 id="housesTotal">...</h2>
                    <div>
                        <h2 id="moneyTotal">...</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <h2>...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "totalMoney" id usually ends up being in excess of £100billion - i want it round it down to the nearest billion and then take away 100 billion from that, so my end figure would be just the top three digits allowing me to easily write "113 billion" instead of "113,666,850,265,875,200,771"

**EDIT:** I've found a bit of code which works for basic math values, but using the figures from my API I get a NaN value instead of what should turn into an abbreviated value? Code below:

```
    var serverRequest = "https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/statistics";
var serverData = "";

function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function abbreviateNumber(value) {
var newValue = value;
if (value >= 1000) {
    var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
    var suffixNum = Math.floor( (""+value).length/3 );
    var shortValue = '';
    for (var precision = 2; precision >= 1; precision--) {
        shortValue = parseFloat( (suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum) ) : value).toPrecision(precision));
        var dotLessShortValue = (shortValue + '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
        if (dotLessShortValue.length <= 2) { break; }
    }
    if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortNum = shortValue.toFixed(1);
    newValue = shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
}
return newValue;
```

}

```
function success(data) {
    document.getElementById("playersTotal").innerHTML = "<span>Total Players: </span>" + numberWithCommas(data['totalplayers']);
    document.getElementById("housesTotal").innerHTML = "<span>Total Houses: </span>" + numberWithCommas(data['totalhouses']);
    document.getElementById("housesTotal").innerHTML = "<span>Total Houses: </span>" + numberWithCommas(data['totalhouses']);
    document.getElementById("moneyTotal").innerHTML = "<span>GDP: </span> £" + numberWithCommas(abbreviateNumber(data.economy['totalcashonhand'] + data.economy['totalcashinbank']));
}

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: serverRequest,
  data: serverData,
  success: success
});
```

Comment: If your API is really returning a number with commas in it, I would try removing them before passing them to abbreviateNumber. A string with numbers and commas in it is NaN (Not a Number).

Comment: My API doesn't do that - it returns a simple numerical value. I have a function called 'numberWithCommas' which turns that numerical value into one with commas

Comment: you posted a lot of code there most of which has nothing to do with your question. Please remove everything that is no a minimal example.

Comment: I agree with bhspencer. And I'm not sure you are accurately describing what you want to do here. 113,666,850,265,875,200,771 rounded down is 113,666,850,265. Taking away 100 billion from that is 13,666,850,265, not 133 billion.

Comment: The main disadvantage of using jQuery is you have to load it. Since you are, because you prefer `$.ajax()` syntax over `XMLHttpRequest` syntax, why aren't you using the advantages of jQuery, such as its consistent, simplified and expressive syntax which, unlike pure JavaScript, works in every browser (because, internally, jQuery applies what you're telling it to according to browser capabilities and peculiarities)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to get the value as-is before passing it to `numberWithCommas`:

```
var moneyTotalInBillions = Math.floor((data.economy['totalcashonhand'] + data.economy['totalcashinbank']) / 1000000000);
document.getElementById("moneyTotal").innerHTML = "<span>GDP: </span> £" + numberWithCommas(moneyTotalInBillions);
```

This adds the moneyTotal together first, divides it by one billion to get the number of billions, and then uses `Math.floor` to remove everything after the decimal point. Adding the integer to your innerHTML string will convert the integer to a string and add them together.

You would need to check and make sure that moneyTotalInBillions is a number bigger than a billion first, otherwise you'll end up with £0.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to to round to the nearest billion.

```js
const number = 113666850265875200771;
const billion = Math.floor(number / 1e9);
console.log(billion + ' Billion'); //113666850265 Billion
```

But, I think you actually want to round to the nearest quintillion.

```js
const number = 113666850265875200771;
const quintillion = Math.floor(number / 1e18);
console.log(quintillion + ' Quintillion'); //113 Quintillion
```

For more large numbers see this chart: [Name of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers#Standard_dictionary_numbers)